# Removing a row form the database when working with the fluent migration

Tags: c#, database-migration, fluent-migrator

I am new to fluent Migrations. I want to simply delete a row from the database can you please guide me how this can be done.
or point me out in the right direction if this questions is already answered elsewhere on stackoverflow.
I dont want to use the dynamic sql in the migration script.

thanks.

Comment: sure however we would like to manage the data updates too as this is updating the configurations and is vitital for the project to have all the data migrations this way.

Comment: If you don't want any change to schema than why don't you delete it as you insert data?

Comment: I know its bit trivial. 
however as I mentioned I am new to using fluent I wasn't sure about the syntax. figured it out though..

Comment: What if you need to delete another row? are you going to delete and record all migration again and again? In my point, you are in the wrong direction.

Comment: yeah true I am with you now. I think migrations are only for the schema changes. All the data changes need to be done either manually or via a script.

Comment: yeah, you can implement with data too but in your case, that's not the good approach. You can use with seeding some default data in your database so any edit in data could be restored after each build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To delete a row in your migration just do the following:

```
//Delete all rows where MyColumn = 123
Delete.FromTable("MyTable").Row(new { MyColumn = "123" });
```

The documentation for FluentMigrator is a great place for questions like this. The article you're looking for can be found [here](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/fluent-interface.html#data-expressions).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from the wiki .
below is the format which can be used to do the migration for deleting row from the database

Delete.FromTable("Users").Row(new { FirstName = "John" }); // delete all rows with FirstName==John